# When break a dll in several dlls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll

I have a .net dll that contains several namespaces with API's that we use in different aplications. The dll size is smaller, only 600k.

Some of this namespaces contain classes related with each other, but other are completely independent.

Not all the namespaces are used in all aplications, some use Config namespace, other only use Log namespace, etc, but if they doesn't use it nothing happens.

The questions are:

1. Do we have to break this dll in several dll's?
2. Which are the benefits of breaking it?
3. Supposing we have 15 namespaces, is it a good decision to break in 15 dlls?

In other situations we detected that have a lot of dll's can produce performance problems loading the .exe or asp.net application, for this reason we decide don't break at the beginning.

Do you have some experience about when is good to break?

Best regards.

Comment: a DLL is a compiled project. if you more DLLs, split your classes and functions out into more projects.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the (Single responsibility principle) from [SOLID](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles.
So, it make sense to divide the dll into some smaller pieces (projects).
If you plan to continue using your DLLs in a future, probably they will grow with more functionality.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. But for example, if you see the System.Core.dll in .net framework, it has several namespaces with single responsability: system.collections, system.diagnostics, system.IO, system.linq, etc. Why not to break this into dll's? for example: System.Linq.dll? Why I have to load all this classes when I'm going to use only System.IO classes?

Comment: Of course, if it is a core library that you will redistribute in almost all your applications, it can have sense to group various small pieces of logic in it.

Answer (score -1):

I usually create a project for each layer of my application. For example, Domain, , Services, Web Services, Data Access, Web View, Mobile View, and so on.

It's more related to functionality than to namespaces.

Comment: Why do you do this break? Are you going to share this dll's with other projects?